# Issue with tabbed content in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very much a beginner & having trouble surfacing tabbed content with HTML and JavaScript (I don't believe the issue is due to my CSS).

Essentially, when I review the HTML file on my local browser, I only see the content in the first tab, but then when I click on tabs 2, 3 or 4, nothing happens. I want to work out how to display content in the correct tab. Can you help?

My HTML:

```js
function openMe(inside) {
  var i, content;
  content = document.getElementByClassName("content");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(inside).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button onclick="openMe('first')" class="tab">FREELANCERS</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('second')" class="tab">GET VERIFIED</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('third')" class="tab">SECURITY</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('forth')" class="tab">SETTINGS</button>
  </div>

  <div id="first" class="content">
    <h2>FREELANCERS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="second" class="content">
    <h2>GET VERIFIED</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="third" class="content">
    <h2>SECURITY</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="forth" class="content">
    <h2>SETTINGS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Liam

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` - plural.

Comment: Use your browser console to check for errors. The messages there will help you immensely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is `document.getElementsByClassName` (with an extra s after Element). Otherwise you'll get an error in your console telling you that the method doesn't exist.

Here it is working nicely with just that simple correction (although you may want to consider whether you actually want all of them displayed at the start, or should some be hidden by default?

```js
function openMe(inside) {
  var i, content;
  content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(inside).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button onclick="openMe('first')" class="tab">FREELANCERS</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('second')" class="tab">GET VERIFIED</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('third')" class="tab">SECURITY</button>
    <button onclick="openMe('forth')" class="tab">SETTINGS</button>
  </div>

  <div id="first" class="content">
    <h2>FREELANCERS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="second" class="content">
    <h2>GET VERIFIED</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="third" class="content">
    <h2>SECURITY</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="forth" class="content">
    <h2>SETTINGS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada turpis non sodales aliquam. Proin vel pretium nunc, eu mattis nibh.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Question should be voted-to-close ;)

Comment: Agree...this hardly requires an answer when a comment and close vote would suffice

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. Its working nicely and I added a the css below to ignore content in tabs two, three and four. 

}

#second, #third, #fourth {
 display: none;;
}

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your javasript function with `document.getElementsByClassName();`

```
function openMe(inside) {
  var i, content;
  content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(inside).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Question should be voted-to-close ;)